# JS visibility of a variable in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I work with JSON and I want to count the number of elements in the response.

```
    $.getJSON("/api/getEvents", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, event) {
            var count = 10;
            $.getJSON("/api/getUsers", function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, event) {
                    alert("Value: " + count);
                    count++;
                });
            });
            alert("Count: " + count);
        });
    });
```

As a result, I get:

```
Value: 10
Value: 11
Value: 12
...
Count: 10
```

Why count = 10?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, that's why I'm not posting this as an answer, but I believe that in $.getJSON you create a closure, which only captures the reference to the variable count.

Comment: It looks to me like `data` from the `getUsers` call is an empty array. You set count to 10, you increment it zero times, then it alerts Count: 10.

Comment: @BenLee No, array is not empty. I can get the value of elements from data.

Comment: When you say "As a result, I get..." what do you mean by "you get"? Is this console output? Alerts? Where are the "Value: ..." lines coming from -- I don't see that in the code anywhere?

Comment: @BenLee Sorry, the parser ate line. Alerts.

Comment: It seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/TfG2C/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because ajax requests are asynchronous. `$.getJSON` just initiates a request, but javascript execution immediately continues. You can see the count if you move the alert inside the ajax callback:

```
$.getJSON("/api/getEvents", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, event) {
        var count = 10;
        $.getJSON("/api/getUsers", function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, event) {
                alert("Value: " + count);
                count++;
            });

            // I moved this here:
            alert("Count: " + count);
        });
        // It used to be here.
    });
});
```

So after you set `var count = 10`, the javascript parser then runs `$.getJSON`, but then *immediately* goes on to the next line, which in your code example alerted the "Count: 10". Then, whenever the request finishes, it runs the callback code that increments the count and alerts the `Value` lines.

Comment: Thats what I thought at first, too but in the question the alert is not where you say it is. It actually is already inside the getJSON callback.

Comment: @Joi, that was a mistake in the question. The OP fixed it after I asked him where the "Value" lines were coming from.